# Molasses - dry vs. wet

Tags: gingerbread

My gingerbread house dough recipe calls for 1 cup of molasses. I live in Europe and could only find a dry version (texture is similar to brown sugar, and is sticky). How do I substitute this dry ingredient when the recipe originally called for the syrupy-version of molasses?

Comment: Can you provide label information for the product you found?  I have *never* heard of dry molasses.

Comment: I believe that this maybe a cultural issue. Living in the U.S. my 'culinary experience' does not extend to "dry molasses" but my [cattle ranching experience DOES](http://www.amazon.com/GreenSense-Dry-Molasses-50-lb/dp/B00025H2T0). **This is a feed supplement for livestock** and I hope this is _not_ what you are looking at. 

Can you provide a manufacturers link to the product you are looking at?

One alternative is that you may have what we would call [Dark Brown Sugar](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/homemade-dark-brown-sugar-recipe/index.html) which is white sugar + molasses

Comment: Do you insist on using this thing? Because if you don't, there are lots of other substitutes for molasses, just about any liquid natural sweetener will do. In fact, gingerbread originates from Europe, and is normally baked with honey, in that sense the American recipe uses molasses as a honey substitute.

Comment: You might have better luck finding treacle, which is the same thing.

Comment: I have only seen dry molasses in the garden center.  Is it safe for human consumption?

Answer (score 4):

The American English term 'molasses' translates to 'dark treacle' in British English. Dried molasses, at least that which I am familiar with, is sulphered blackstrap molasses (the darkest, most bitter variety) and typically used as animal feed or as a soil amendment.

If you can't find dark treacle and your recipe calls for white sugar substitute golden syrup (similar to a very light molasses) or honey for the molasses and substitute brown sugar (which is a mixture of white refined sugar and molasses) for white sugar to up the molasses flavor with dark brown sugar preferred as it has more molasses added. Pack the brown sugar and substitute 1:1 on a volumetric basis.

Answer (score 3):

The dry molasses is an excellent commodity in case you run out of the regular version. It is great for boating since it is easier to store. It can be used in BBQ sauce, banana bread, ginger cookies, rye bread. If you need to add moisture to it, the recommended ratio is 3/4 molasses powder to 1/4 water.

Answer (score -1):

Use honey instead, it's not worth it.

Comment: That would give a *very* different flavour than molasses. It could be very good, but if they *want* the flavour of molasses, then honey won't do. Also, I find honey usually isn't as thick as molasses so it might not produce the same texture.